# Symfony How to force Remember Me with Login Link?

Tags: authentication, symfony, remember-me

I'm working on a project app where i've added the possibility for a team leader to add members in his team. Then i added a link which sends a login link for the members of the team.

I would like to force the "Remember Me" specifically for the members of the team. they would have to login just once using the link in the mail, and then they could close the browser and go back later and they would still be logged in.

Here is my security.yaml

```
login_link:
    check_route: login_check
    signature_properties: [ 'id' ]
    lifetime: 900 #15minutes
```

And here is the function in the controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/magic", name="app_magic")
 */
public function magic(UserRepository $userRepository, LoginLinkHandlerInterface $loginLinkHandler, MailerInterface $mailer): Response
{
    $users = $userRepository->findBy(['chefEquipe' => $this->getUser()]);

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $loginLinkDetails = $loginLinkHandler->createLoginLink($user);
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from('email@test.com')
            ->to($user->getEmail())
            ->subject('Magic login link')
            ->text('You can use this link to login: ' . $loginLinkDetails->getUrl());

        $mailer->send($email);
    }

    $this->addFlash('message', 'Un mail de connexion a été envoyé aux membres de votre équipe');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_test_registration_team');

}
```

How could i do that without activating always remember me so that it does not affect the 'admin' user ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You could have it default checked in the login template, would that not work for you? Trouble is with the login is that when it is anonymous, you can't determine if they're admin or not at that stage..

Comment: Doesn't have a template for login link, users log in just by clicking the link

Comment: I think i see what you're trying to do but i don't think it is a good design regarding security. "*they would have to login just once using the link in the mail*", how are they entering their credentials (username and password)?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable always_remember_me in configs:

```
firewalls:
    ...
    main:
        ...
        remember_me:
            ...
            always_remember_me: true
```

Comment: Not possible, i want only user logged in by login link to have remember me, not classic users